# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [X] and [Y] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/CreationClient] which is not permitted

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I can not start Tomcat: Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [CreationClient] and [com.sdz.tp.servlets.CreationClient] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/CreationClient] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2466)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2148)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2109)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1293)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
4 janv. 2014 19:57:38 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
```

The problem is probably with my `web.xml`:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>tp1</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CreationClient</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sdz.tp.servlets.CreationClient</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CreationCommande</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sdz.tp.servlets.CreationCommande</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CreationClient</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CreationClient</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CreationCommande</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CreationCommande</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: English monsieur, do you speak it?

Comment: Sorry @user3161023, although there is a [Stack Overflow (in French)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50998/stack-overflow-in-french) going through the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) approvals process, until that site is created, Questions and Answers on *Stack Overflow* are expected to be in English.

Comment: Yes i speak a little bit...

Answer (score 5):

Try removing the `@WebServlet` annotation from class `com.sdz.tp.servlets.CreationClient`. The servlet mapping can be defined either in `web.xml` or using an annotation, but not both.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried but now i have an error 404!

Comment: Then it's a different problem. I suggest you ask a new question with the details, e.g. which URL you are calling.

Comment: How can i join an zip of my project please?

Comment: You can't. You should include the parts of your code that are significant to the problem in the question text. See also http://sscce.org/

Comment: +1 for right ans dude :)

Comment: This error usually occurs in case of wrong XML file. Either its web.xml or context.xml.